# How to sync Ethereum coins deposits without reading blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, web3js-v1.x

As we know Ethereum network processes more than one million transactions in 24 hours. I have a set of projects where I have to read all the blocks and inside transactions to find deposit on my addresses. Its a centralised exchange and buy/sell platforms.

Tried to achieve it via blockbook, but its too costly than a running a full node. Why the blockchains doesn't provide an easy solutions for the developers where need not to traverse each and every block to find the deposits.

It's going to be a pain for the developers to sync each and every block. If the service stopped for few hours, the cron service remains behind and it takes too much time to process the pending blocks.

Why don't blockchains doesn't have a easy/straight forwarded way to sync the deposits?

Please guide me if I'm doing something wrong.